# How to push branch to remote

Tags: git, github

I have 2 branches in my local system named `A` and `B`. I checkout to `B` means now I am in `B`. I wrote some code, commited in that branch itself but I didn't push the branch to remote. Now I checkout to `A`, where I am facing some problems so I want to push `B` to remote.

Is it possible to push from a branch to another branch?

I am facing this problems in Branch `A`:

- After checkout from `B` to `A`, it shows `public/index.html: Permission denied`.
- I tried to checkout to `B` from `A` but it's not allowing me. It shows the following message:

  `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
      public/index.html
  Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
  Aborting`.

How not to lose the code that I wrote in branch `B`?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$ git push origin B:refs/heads/B
```

Comment: I ran your first command,but it showing `$ git stash
public/index.html: Permission denied
No local changes to save`.Even though I ran remaining commands It's not working.

Comment: Try it like this `$ sudo git stash`

Comment: So you are on Windows. It seems like a permission issue. Can you fix the permissions of that particular file and the `public/` folder? They need to be writable for the user you run `git` from.

Comment: I don't know about that,all those permissions are handle by `teamlead`,he is not available today.So I just want to push branch `b`.Is there any way to push forcefully.

Comment: What about now? Updated my answer.

Comment: really thank you.. I pushed branch to remote.Now I want to fix the issue.Why I am not able to merge.

Comment: Please post another question with your new issue, since the original question is now answered :)

Comment: After restarting my server, It's not not showing any message.Successfully I merged.I don't know the reason.

Comment: Probably the server was using the file so you could not edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Do `git push origin the_other_branch_name`

It's ok to do it while you working are in another branch with either unstaged or staged files (I just tried it).

Answer (score 0):

Before moving on to any other branch, you can either temporarily save them to be able to restore them later ( read stash them ) or commit the changes for that particular branch.

Your changes will always be safe if you have done any of the above.

I think, here you would want to stash your changes instead of pushing the branch B's changes to the remote.

"git stash" is the command for saving all the changes temporarily. You can restore these changes on any branch.